# In excel, How to calculate cricket overs completed and overs left to bowl from a cricket table?

Tags: excel

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvyi4.png) will give an idea what I exactly looking for. The completed cells calculated and return the overs completed value and the empty cells calculated the remaining overs value. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use these formula

Balls (`B23`) `=120-COUNTBLANK(B2:G21)`

Overs (`B24`) `=INT(B23/6)+MOD(B23,10)/10`

Overs left (`B25`) `=20-B24`

`B2:G21` is the range marked as red boxes(combined) in your image

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert 4 extra col after Over Total. 
1 Over Status 2 Over Comp 3 Over Rem 4 Total Ovrs

To find Total Runs in I2 write this,, 
=if(and(b2<>"", c2<>"", d2<>"", e2<>"", f2<>"", g2<>"", h2<>""), sum(b2:h2), "")

To find Over status in J2 write this,, 
=if(and(I2>=0,I2<> "")," OvrCom", "OvrRem")

IN K2 =Countif(J2:J6," OvrCom")

IN L2 =Countif(J2:J6, "OvrRem")

IN M2 =(k2+L2)

NB I've calculated using 5 over, you adjust cell add accordingly.

Comment: Hi Nightcrawler the solution you have suggested is not working properly, I've tested it, plz check mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your idea of subtracting the overs completed from 20 but I didn't get right answer.

Dear Rajesh S, I am not ok to add more columns and would like to put it bit simple.

Finally, I have found a solution by myself for this, here it is
=INT(COUNTBLANK(B2:G21)/6)+MOD(COUNTBLANK(B2:G21),6)/10 
and this one works fine for me.

How ever Thank you very much both of you for your time and answers for my question.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as my solution??

Comment: In your solution, I got the overs completed in B24 but when you subtract that barely from 20 then it doesn't give an expected result. for example B24 is 11.1 and when you do (20-11.1) you will get 8.9 instead of 8.5. There is nothing like 8.9 in cricket. But when you use the formula I posted you can get the expected result. Please check when you got time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=(120-INT(F110))+IF(MOD(F110,1)=0,0,0.6-MOD(F110,1)-1)
```

That's the formula I have.  You can change the 120 to whatever like 300.

F110 is the Total Overs cell.

So as simple as that.  Just put that formula in the cell you want and replace the F110 to the cell you have for your Total Overs and it will work.